# pointer to pointers of vector and arrays

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a map mapping a character to a 2-d array of rules to process that character. Following is the code:

```
struct CFG //this struct is data structure to contain a context free grammar
{
   vector<char> *V;
   vector<char> *T;
   map<char,vector<vector<rhs>*>*> *prod;
  // char start;
};

int main()
{
map<char,vector<vector<rhs>*>*> *prod;  //rhs is the type of each cell of the 2-d array
CFG cfg1;
cfg1.V= new vector<char>;

//We imput elements into the V array here......//

cfg1.prod= new map<char,vector<vector<rhs>*>*>;

for(int i=0;i<cfg1.V->size();i++)
 {
    vector<vector<rhs>*>* all_prod_of_one_nonter= new vector<vector<rhs>*>;
    *(cfg1.prod)[*(cfg1.V)[i]]=all_prod_of_one_nonter;  //error occurs here//////
 }
}
```

In the line, I marked as 'error occurs', the following error occurs:

```
q1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
q1.cpp:93:29: error: no match for ‘operator*’ in ‘**(cfg1.CFG::V + ((unsigned int)(((unsigned int)i) * 12u)))’
```

I use * to dereference the pointer cfg1.V so that I can use subscript notation to access the array cells. How to remove the error?

Comment: This is extremely non-idiomatic C++.  You should strongly consider **not** using a pointer to a map of pointers to vectors of pointers to vectors.  Basically, just get rid of all the pointers entirely; you'll find the resulting code a lot simpler.

Comment: So many asterisk, aaargh.

Comment: You don't really need any of the pointers, they are all non-functional in your code. Start by removing all the `*` s and `->`s and `new`s.

Comment: Use a reference - Also you have memory leaks.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth...you are correct..But, I am in the process of learning about STL in c++ and trying to get comfortable in using them along with pointers.Hence the labyrinth..

Comment: @andre...where is the leak?

Comment: @avinash The correct question is: Where does it *not* leak? Pretty much everything in there leaks all its allocated memory. Worse, since you initialize your pointers from outside the struct instead of in a ctor, you have no control over them and therefore you couldn't even write an effective dtor even if you wanted to.

Comment: @andre...I thought that memory leak occured when there is an allocated space in memory which was inaccessible(example if I do 'int p; int *a= new int; a= &p;', then the allocated space cannot be accessed). But here all the allocated spaces can be accessed. If I am wrong please tell me and specify a link where I can read about this.

Answer (score 1):

```
(*cfg1.prod)[(*cfg1.V)[i]]=all_prod_of_one_nonter;
```

(Reason: `operator[]` (array subscripting) binds more tightly than `operator*` (indirection).)

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure it did, but still, please consider Oli Charlesworth's advice in the comments to your question.

Comment: On second thought, it shouldn't have worked because the same problem persists within the array subscript. Edited answer to reflect this.

Comment: @us2012..inside I had changed the subscript and instead had used at function. So, it worked.